# Proper way to call firestore functions inside React components

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-context

I am developing a React project with firestore as a backend, and I'm quite new on this technology.

How is the recommended way to call firestore functions (addDoc, updateDoc, specific fetch queries, etc...) inside a React component?
I want to avoid using firestore methods directly, and replace that with a custom hook, class or similar but I need to know the prper way of doing that in terms of good code practices and/or performance.

Comment: You can watch youtube tutorials.

Comment: For stuff like this documentation is the best way to go.